# Eigenvalues of a matrix given its derivative.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

As noted in the comments, the following notations will be used:

- $\lambda_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue (presumably listed by descending magnitude)
- $|v_i\rangle$ is the $i^{th}$ column eigenvector
- $\langle v_i|$ is the $i^{th}$ row eigenvector

---

Suppose I have a large matrix $A(x,t)$ depending on two free parameters (so each input of $A$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $t$).  Let
$$
B(x,t)=\frac \partial {\partial t}A(x,t)\\
C(x,t)=\frac \partial {\partial  x}B(x,t)
$$
If I know all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, and I know all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $C$, then can I use that information to find the complete eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$?

I know that if such a relationship exists that it is non-trivial, since, for example, if
$$
A=\sum \lambda_i |v_i\rangle\langle v_i|,
$$
then $B$ is given by
$$
B=\sum (\frac \partial {\partial t}\lambda_i) |v_i\rangle\langle v_i|+ \lambda_i  |\frac \partial {\partial t}v_i\rangle\langle v_i|+ \lambda_i  |v_i\rangle\langle \frac \partial {\partial t}v_i|,
$$
which shows that $B$ is not diagonalized the same as $A$, but surely a relationship must exist between them.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your notation (or I'm not familiar with it): What is $$\lambda_i | v_i \rangle \langle v_i|$$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Very sorry, it is common notation in physics and engineering. $\lambda_i$ is the ith eigenvalue, and $|v_i\rangle$ (resp. $\langle v_i|$) is the ith column (resp. row) eigenvector.  It is a convenient way of represented the Jordon decomposition for a diagonalizable matrix.